# How to recover from key error in mongoose + express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, mongoose

I've created a Contact form using mongoose and express 3

Its possible the user already exists with that username, in which case I get an err.code 46:29  (duplicate key). How should I handle existing users?

This is what I'm doing now....but I'm not sure checking error code is best way:

`

```
`const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//load model
const Contact = require('./models/contact');
//load database url



const app = express();

const port = 8000;
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs.engine({
    defaultLayout: 'main'
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.render('home'); 
});

app.get('/about',(req,res) => {
    res.render('about');
});

app.get('/contact',(req,res) => {
    res.render('contact');
});

// handle POST route for contact
app.post('/contactus',(req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const newContact = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        message: req.body.message,
        date: new Date()
    }
    new Contact(newContact).save((err,contact) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.redirect('/success');
        return;
    });
});

app.get('/success',(req,res) => {
    res.render('success');
});

//load database url login 


    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dating', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology:      true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`CONNECTED TO MONGO!`);
      })
    .catch((err) => {
         console.log(`OH NO! MONGO CONNECTION ERROR!`);
        console.log(err);
     })

   app.listen(port,() => {
       console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
    });`
```

`

Its possible the user already exists with that username, in which case I get an err.code 46:29